# Qgis libqgispython.so failed to load

Tags: qgis, python, ubuntu

I am using Qgis 1.8 and Python (on Ubuntu 12.10) for a couple of month now, but today i got suddenly the error

*Couldn't load Python support library: Cannot load library /usr/lib/qgispython: (/usr/lib/libqgispython.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)*

while starting qgis. I reinstalled Qgis but nothing happend. Is there a possibility to reinstall this library?

Comment: I think there is another package called qgis-python (or similar, I'm not using Ubuntu, so I'm just guessing the name. If it doesn't work, best to use `apt-cache search qgis` and look out for a good match containing py or python)

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-qgis python-qgis-common

Comment: @Luke when run this line it says _0 updated, 0 reinstalled, 0 removed and 0 not updated_ and nothing happend

Comment: I have tried it with sudo apt-get --purge remove qgis and reinstall qgis again but it has also no effect

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-qgis python-qgis-common`

Comment: Its is also not working. I even reinstalled ubuntu... First i installed 1.7 and python was working. Afterwards 1.8 and the error appeared again.

Comment: @Martin were you able to solve the problem? I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, and QGIS 2.8.1 and it "couldn't load Python etc."